# Multiple joins in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Writing codes for football fantasy league. Have two tables

1. `Player_details`

   Columns - `ID,PLAYER_NAME,POINTS`
2. `USERS`

   Columns - `id,palyer1,player2,player3,........Player11,`

Users create accounts selecting 11 players in the team. The team total is sum of points earned by players from Players details table.

I want to get the total for each user. Let me put an example:

```
USER       player1    player2   player3  Player4 ... ..... ...Player11  Total 

User1        a         b          c        d                      j
user2        d         a          e        b                      k
```

.
.
.

a,b,c.... are players name from players table. Now in the total column i want get sum of points scored by player a,b,c,d,...j for User1.

and same for user2,user3,user4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not even asking a question. This rather looks like homework which would make you someone that's too lazy to do their homework.

Comment: This table appears to be in desperate need of a redesign. See normalisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably do what you want. Note that because of your table structure you have to do a join for every player on the team. As was noted in the comments, you should look into [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

```
SELECT u.id AS User,
  p1.PLAYER_NAME AS Player1,
  p2.PLAYER_NAME AS Player2,
  p3.PLAYER_NAME AS Player3,
  p4.PLAYER_NAME AS Player4,
  p5.PLAYER_NAME AS Player5,
  p6.PLAYER_NAME AS Player6,
  p7.PLAYER_NAME AS Player7,
  p8.PLAYER_NAME AS Player8,
  p9.PLAYER_NAME AS Player9,
  p10.PLAYER_NAME AS Player10,
  p11.PLAYER_NAME AS Player11,
  p1.POINTS + p2.POINTS + p3.POINTS + p4.POINTS + p5.POINTS + p6.POINTS + p7.POINTS + p8.POINTS + p9.POINTS + p10.POINTS + p11.POINTS AS Total
FROM USERS u
JOIN Player_details p1 ON p1.ID = u.player1
JOIN Player_details p2 ON p2.ID = u.player2
JOIN Player_details p3 ON p3.ID = u.player3
JOIN Player_details p4 ON p4.ID = u.player4
JOIN Player_details p5 ON p5.ID = u.player5
JOIN Player_details p6 ON p6.ID = u.player6
JOIN Player_details p7 ON p7.ID = u.player7
JOIN Player_details p8 ON p8.ID = u.player8
JOIN Player_details p9 ON p9.ID = u.player9
JOIN Player_details p10 ON p10.ID = u.player10
JOIN Player_details p11 ON p11.ID = u.player11
```

Comment: Thanks @nick, query worked perfectly as desired. I am too not happy with the database structure. I am just started working on this fantasy League, If asked what would be ideal database structure you suggest.I  just  have user details, players who play

Comment: It's a good question. Any structure will have advantages and disadvantages for inserts and selects. This structure as you can see is very bad for selects but would be very easy for inserts. A structure for the user table which just had user_id, player_number and player_id (so each user would have 11 rows in the table) would be easier for selects (less joins) but harder for inserts. It mostly comes down to which operation you expect to do the most. The last structure also makes it easier to change the number of players on a team...Try googling the problem and you should find more guidance